# How Can I Log a Generic Type's Value Using OSLog?

Tags: swift, logging

I have the following method that wraps `UserDefaults` so that I can interact with the API in a type-safe way.

```swift
public func item<T>(forKey key: Key<T>) -> T? {
    var item: T?
    defer {
        #if DEBUG
        os_log(item != nil ? "Returned value for key '%@'" : "Returned 'nil' for key '%@'", log: Defaults.defaultsLog, type: .debug, key.value)
        #endif
    }
    if let value = defaults.value(forKey: key.value) as? T, value is FoundationCodable || value is SwiftCodable {
        item = value
        return value
    }
    guard let data = defaults.data(forKey: key.value) else { return nil }
    guard let decoded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else { return nil }
    item = decoded
    return decoded
}
```

I want to log the returned value using:

```swift
func os_log(_ message: StaticString, dso: UnsafeRawPointer? = #dsohandle, log: OSLog = default, type: OSLogType = default, _ args: CVarArg...)
```

However, my generic type, `T`, does not conform to `CVarArg`.

Is it possible to log the returned value? If so, then how do I structure my logic to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log `String(description:decoded) as NSString`.